# How do I change the sort order of items in Google's top navigation bar?

Tags: google-account

I guess this certainly qualifies as a "first world problem", but recently the link to Google Reader disappeared from the top navigation bar across all my Google Account services (Gmail, Calendar, etc).  Now the Google Reader link is an extra click away because it's under the "More" drop down:

[image]

I have seen some similar questions about adding custom shortcuts to the top bar using various browser extensions for Firefox or Chrome, but I don't want to do that. I was hoping there is a configuration setting somewhere that I'm just not finding.

Comment: as far as I know, you can't without some page-modifying extension.  What I really wonder if why Google hates Reader so much???  This is the second time they have hidden the link!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this UI has not been available for some time. Even if answerable, no one can use the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now [rearrange the order of the elements in the new grid-like menu](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2014/03/rearrange-apps-in-googles-navigation.html) (the top navigation bar is obsolete) by clicking and dragging them in the order you desire.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I searched for awhile until I found the best solution so far. Many of the posts I read so far didn't work for me. (Stop reading if you hate the new Google dropdown menu.)

Disclaimers:

- This method uses the new Google dropdown (many people hate it)
- I have only seen this work in Google Search, Gmail, Google Reader. So far not in iGoogle as it must have a different cookie
- Will only work in Chrome (I am using 16.0.912.63)

  1. Add new Google dropdown menu by changing your cookie: http://www.paulspoerry.com/2011/google-navigation-how-to-enable-the-new-navigation-now/ (Remember to change the TLD domain in the cookie if you use a different TLD from ".com" such as ".google.ca")
  2. Add "[Big G Dropdown Sorter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiamgkpplhllmgmjkmpoapkidpgfhmdo)" Extension:
  3. Now go to gmail.com or google.com and click on top-left icon to access the menu. Drag and drop as you please!

Answer (score -1):

Working instructions 7/4/14:

1. Click on the cog wheel (settings) in top right;
2. Click on *Edit site layout*;
3. Click on top navigation bar title with drop downs that you would like to re-arrange;
4. By selecting them and using the arrows on the right you can move them up or down and change their level to become a drop-down option or a title within a drop-down option.

Comment: Are you sure you have answered the right question? Your answer seems to be about Google Sites, while question is about the navigation bar that used to sit on top of all Google services. And Google Reader is long gone, by the way.